# How do I specify the a specific dummy variable with SymPy Integration

Tags: python, sympy, integral

I was trying to run a SymPy integration where I created my own variables, and the integral is

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn
import math
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import scipy.special as special
from sympy import init_session

init_session()
%matplotlib inline

dP, dT = symbols('dP dT', real = True, positive = True)
dr = symbols('dr', real = True, positive = True)
T_9, T = symbols('T_9 T', real = True, positive = True)
rho, mu, m_u, k, P, gamma = symbols('rho mu m_u k P gamma', real = True, positive = True)
r, R_solar, R = symbols('r R_solar R', real = True, positive = True)
G, M_solar, M = symbols('G M_solar M', real = True, positive = True)
a, c, kappa = symbols('a c kappa', real = True, positive = True)
F = symbols('F', real = True, positive = True)

cc = (T / (rho * k * T / (mu * m_u)) * (1 - (1 / gamma)) * ((-rho * G * M / r**2)))

r_int = integrate(((cc), (0, r, R)))
```

I tried changing the limits to specify what I wanted, but I kept getting the same error; the error is: `ValueError: specify dummy variables for (T / (rho * k * T / (mu * m_u)) * (1 - (1 / gamma)) * ((-rho * G * M / r**2)))`.

Comment: Please specify/write out the error you get

Comment: When presenting an example for something like SO you should strip out imports of anything that is not needed.

Comment: The error is `ValueError: specify dummy variables for (T / (rho * k * T / (mu * m_u)) * (1 - (1 / gamma)) * ((-rho * G * M / r**2)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote the wrong integrate command. For a definite integral it should be like this: `integrate(expr, (symbol, lower, upper))`. Assuming `r` is the integration variable, your example will be:

```
r_int = integrate(cc, (r, 0, R))
```